# When viewing the history of a file, how can you get a double-click to compare with the previous version?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, visual-studio-2017, tfvc

Using TFVC in Visual Studio, when I right-click a folder and click on View History, it opens the History view with the source location set to that folder. When I double-click a specific changeset, it opens that changeset's details in Team Explorer. Excellent. And then when I double-click a file in the Changeset Details, it automatically compares that changeset's version of the file with the previous version so I can see what actual changes were made to a file in that specific changeset. Perfect.

However, when the source location in the History view is set to a file, double-clicking a changeset just opens that version of the file rather than opening the Changeset Details. This is fairly useless, seeing as I use History to compare and not to just view. Is there a way to change the double-click behavior in this case? Opening the Changeset Details would be good. Automatically jumping to "Compare with Previous Version" would be better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you view the history for a single file , you could right click the changesest select **Changeset Details** or directly click the [image] shotcut.

[image]

Then you could also see the changeset details in **Team Explorer**, select the specific file in changeset details, double click it, will get the same result as view a folder level history you described above.

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I should've mentioned that I knew about the right-click option already. I didn't know about the shortcut button though, so thank you! This doesn't explain how to change the double-click behavior or how to get to the Compare view without having to open Changeset Details, but I'll accept the answer if nothing else comes in soon.

Comment: @KyleDelaney Yes I'm afraid you couldn't change the double-click behavior, it's by designed and integrated  with Visual Studio. You have to use the workaround above.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is any way to change the behaviour. I would think, the thinking would have been that you are already in the context of file and are clicking on the file from a history view. So it's showing you that particular version

Comment: Okay, but what if I want to view all the changes that have been made to a particular file?

Comment: When you are in history view for a particular file, that is what you are viewing

Comment: No it's not. It shows me a list of changesets but not what has actually changed. When I say changes, I mean the individual changes to the file that you can see when you're using Compare.

Comment: You can do it using either of the two options. Select two changeset, right click and select "Compare" or right click on your change and click annotate. The former option will show you delta between two changes. The later option will show you changes made across changesets. 

If you are asking to view the delta between changes by just clicking on one changeset. it's not the Visual studio behavior. The reason I have already mentioned is that you are already in the context of a file